# Getting ORA-22054 underflow error and ORA-22053 overflow error

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle

[image: ORA-22054 underflow error]

This example use Visual Studio 2013 and Oracle.DataAccess.dll
Problem happens because oracle parameter. You must set parameters as array.

```vb
Dim sql As String
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim da As OracleDataAdapter
Dim cmd As OracleCommand
Dim params(3) As OracleParameter

Using conn As New OracleConnection(OracleConnString)
    sql = "select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 from table1 " & _
          "where col1 like '%'||:pValue1||'%' and col2 = :pValues2 " & _
          "and col3 = :pValue3 and col4 = :pValue4"
    conn.Open()

    params(0) = New OracleParameter(":pValue1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, vValue1, ParameterDirection.Input)
    params(1) = New OracleParameter(":pValue2", OracleDbType.Int32, vValue2, ParameterDirection.Input)
    params(2) = New OracleParameter(":pValue3", OracleDbType.Varchar2, vValue3, ParameterDirection.Input)
    params(3) = New OracleParameter(":pValue4", OracleDbType.Date, vValue4, ParameterDirection.Input)

    cmd = New OracleCommand(sql, conn)
    If Not Paramaters Is Nothing Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To params.Length - 1
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Paramaters(i))
        Next
    End If

    dt = New DataTable
    da = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
    da.Dispose()
    conn.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-22054 Underflow Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631563/ora-22054-underflow-error) Looks like one of the values you're passing doesn't match table structure. Remember that oracle numeric datatypes need to be little larger than .net types because there is no direct mapping

Comment: If you solved your problem, either write your own answer and accept or delete the question (in this case this is preferable) because it brings no value to the community. But don't change your question, marking it as "SOLVED"

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your advice.